# CSRF protection in singlepage web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

My Application structure as follows

1)API server running in api.mydomain.com

2)Frontend VUejs application running in www.mydomain.com

So i implemented authentication via httponly cookie.

But little confused with CSRF token implementation

Mysolution

1).`CSRF` token from the url like `/getCSRF`.

2) Store it in localstorage.

3) Send with every request.

But i don't think its the good way does anyone have suggestion?

Comment: Just don't use cookie-based authentication for a SPA. Use JWT or OAuth or your own token algorithm. No cookies - no CSRF.

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation?? as i understand  store the auth token in httponly cookie and validate every request with token??

Comment: Do you understand how the [CSRF attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) works? Do you know why you need the CSRF token?

Comment: As far as i know CSRF token ensure that the request is originates from our server so that other evil websites can't make request to our website

Comment: @Dmitry coming to your point if i  change cookie based auth to token based the storage of token stills a problem the most secure way is to store it in httponly cookie but again am i  vulnarable to CSRF?? because cookies are passed every request without consider the origin of the request

Comment: If the token expires in an hour or so (or with a sliding window) the same way as a session cookie does then I see no problem.

Comment: My question am i still vulnerable even if  the token stored in http only cookie??

Comment: Yes, all cookies are sent with every request. `httponly` part means that JavaScript has no access to it. You still will need CSRF tokens.

Comment: i don't thin token expiration is better method bcz whenever the token is valid i am still vulnerable to CSRF

Comment: If you don't use cookies you are not vulnerable to CSRF attack by definition.

Comment: if i don't use cookies where can i store tokens its in locastorage??  but its not a good approach by default loaclstorage is accessible via javascript so an XSS attack leads to easily exposed my auth token

Comment: Do you load content from untrusted sources into your SPA? If not what XSS are you talking about?

Comment: yes load content from untrusted sources

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: Feel free to use session-based authentication in combination with the httpOnly (prevents your session cookie to be hijacked via XSS attack) cookie. Nothing wrong with that.

After a certain action (e.g. login), generate a CSRF token and store it in a cookie (make it accessible to JavaScript). You can HMAC the token with server secret so that attacker cannot recreate a CSRF.

Sure that CSRF will be sent as a cookie in each request, but the trick is to send it and expect it in a custom header (e.g. `X-CSRF-HEADER`). The final step is to check its validity.

The key idea is that attacker cannot attach custom headers while performing a CSRF attack.